# Creating a stored procedure with utf8 strings

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, utf-8

I have a stored procedure with some Cyrillic strings inside. I want to check a table with a char column if the column contains some specific strings, some of them in Cyrillic. The problem seems to be that I cannot create the procedure with those strings.

```
SET NAMES utf8;

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists testutf8
//
create procedure testutf8()
begin
    select 'ξενοδοχια';
end
//
delimiter ;


call testutf8();
```

Returns
?????????

```
show create procedure testutf8;
```

returns

Procedure   testutf8

sql_mode    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Create Procedure "CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `testutf8`() begin select '?????????'; end"

character_set_client    utf8

collation_connection    utf8_general_ci

Database Collation latin1_swedish_ci

So despite me using SET NAMES UTF8; the server turns my code into latin1 it seems. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding ?characterEncoding=utf8 to the server url did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

In store procedure input variable added

```
CHARSET utf8
```

So it look like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `post_content`(IN postName varchar(255), IN contentEn longtext, IN contentAR longtext CHARSET utf8, IN contentKU longtext CHARSET utf8)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists testutf8
//
create procedure testutf8()
begin
   select CAST('ξενοδοχια' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: This did not change the result, sorry